# moment js: weird utc convert for timezone: Kiritimati Island, UTC+14

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Please, help to sort out how `momentjs` deal with one unique timezone: `Kiritimati Island, UTC+14`

I want to get clear date, without hours and minutes, just year, month and day in utc.

I do:

```
const date = new Date(1950, 3, 15);
const formatted = moment(date).utc(true).format();
console.log(formatted);
```

In any timezone, from UTC-12 to UTC+13, I get:

```
1950-04-15T00:00:00Z // I'd like to get this for all the timezones
```

In timezone Kiritimati Island, UTC+14, I get:

```
1950-04-14T23:55:00Z // unwanted result
```

Can I get the same date for all the timezones, Kiritimati included?

PS: I change timezones in Data & time settings, Windows10

[Plunk](https://jsfiddle.net/eqyxkbgv/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very strange issue, it seems that there is an error of 5 minutes in moment.js for this timezone. The offset from UTC should be 10h40m, but it's 10h45m.

And it only seems to happen for older dates, well, before October 1979.

It's also present on Ubuntu 18, I had thought it might be a Windows thing, but doesn't look like it.

I would imagine it's worth reporting this as a bug, oh wait it looks like it already exists: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5454

In any case there is a workaround using the [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) library.

```js
const date = new Date(1950, 3, 15);
const dateMoment = moment(date).utc(true).format();

const tz = moment.tz.guess(true); // Get moment-timezone to guess user timezone.
const dateMomentTZ = moment.tz(date, tz).utc(true).format();

document.getElementById("mom").innerText = dateMoment;
document.getElementById("momtz").innerText = dateMomentTZ;
document.getElementById("tz").innerText = tz;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script> 

Original - with issue: <b id="mom"></b><br>
Moment.tz - workaround: <b id="momtz"></b><br>
Timezone: <b id="tz"></b>
```

Comment: Yep, I've reported this. Thank you for workaround, that's cool!

Comment: Great, glad to help. I must dive into the code to see if I can understand why this is happening. Also checkout Luxon - it's the successor to Moment.js https://moment.github.io/luxon/